# Excel - Sort by x - 0000xx000000

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I have a list in Excel that i need to sort. But i need to sort on number xx in the following format:

1. 1234xx123456
2. 3541xx548135

So if xx in the first row is 68, and the xx in the second row is 45, they would change place. Is there any way of doing this in Excel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Couldn't you just extract the 4th and 5th characters into another cell and sort on that?

```
B1:   =mid(A1,5,2)
```

Then sort on column b?

Comment: Right idea.  Use this: `=VALUE(MID(A1,5,2))`

Comment: Thanks my original pseudocode included the value part, but was edited out by @AdamV

Comment: I agree with Excellll. This should also work: `=0+MID(A1,5,2)`

Comment: Sorry if I mucked anything up translating from pseudo to real Excel. I nearly posted a new answer but wanted you to get the credit for the right idea. 0+ or VALUE() are fine to convert the text to number for "proper" sorting, but if these are always fixed length as two-digit numbers they will sort properly anyway even if left as text, so there's no need really.